# Inner Join to Same Table Twice on same column

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

I'm having a problem with a SQL Server query trying to join a view with another view twice

```
SELECT 
    FAC.* 
FROM 
    ViewFacturacionDiaria_Test AS FAC
INNER JOIN
    ViewInformacionRepresentantes AS REP
        ON REP.RepIDTabacal = FAC.Vendedor
INNER JOIN
    ViewInformacionRepresentantes AS REP2
        ON REP2.RepIDCtayOrden = FAC.Vendedor
WHERE
    FecCpbte BETWEEN '2015-11-28' AND '2015-11-30'
```

In the "FAC" view I have sales information, in the other one I have a specific group of sales person which I want to filter from the main view.

I would like to understand why the query is returning an empty resultset.

Comment: There is probably a mismatch in the records due to the `INNER JOIN` where the keys aren't present in all the records.  If you change to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, at least temporarily to get table records where there are no matches, does that show anything?

Comment: If I change to LEFT OUTER JOIN it works but it brings all the records from the main view including the ones I need. If I dissable one of inner joins, no matter which one, the query works properly; I don't know why can't work the two at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot comment.  But I believe Peter is right in his comment.  Since you are using 2 inner joins they both need to return results.  Are you expecting both joins to find a match?

Try this and see which column is null.  That is the join that is resulting in no returned rows.

```
SELECT 
    FAC.Vendedor
    ,REP.RepIDTabacal
    ,REP2.RepIDCtayOrden
FROM 
    ViewFacturacionDiaria_Test AS FAC
LEFT JOIN
    ViewInformacionRepresentantes AS REP ON
    REP.RepIDTabacal = FAC.Vendedor
LEFT JOIN
    ViewInformacionRepresentantes AS REP2 ON
    REP2.RepIDCtayOrden = FAC.Vendedor
WHERE
    FecCpbte BETWEEN '2015-11-28' AND '2015-11-30'
```

Comment: Thank you both. I used the query above with and added some filters at the where clause so I got what I was looking for. I had misconception about the inner join so your query clear it out for me. Thank you again.